# Convert french accents to percent encoding

Tags: java, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have a simple

```
String abc = "réunion";
```

I should convert this string into the URL percent encoding - so I need:

```
String abc = "r%c3%a9union";
```

Any simple solution for this?

Comment: That's not UTF-8, that URL percent encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @Mat - Actually there is an encoding involved here as well. How do you convert é to byte pattern first otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this class:

```
         java.net.URLEncoder
```

For example, for encoding as UTF:

```
     import java.net.URLEncoder; 
     .....
     String utf_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(url.toString(),"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
URLEncoder.encode("réunion", "UTF-8")
```